# Make google assistant voice activated with the "Ok, Google"

Tags: google-assistant-sdk

I would like to set my google assitant to be activated by Voice(Ok, Google).

In case of Google Assistant Library, Hands-free activation(voice activation) is supported.

But in case of Google Assistant Service, this feature is not supported accorign to https://developers.google.com/assistant/sdk/overview.

I have built Google-Assistant-Service based on Cpp Language.

Is there any possible way Google-Assistant-Service to be activated by voice?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The service is a set of gRPC calls to a server backend whereas a voice activation process would be local. If you have a hotword detection model you can feed audio data into it and then start a request once you detect the phrase.